# How to handle student record who completed their studies

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am making students result record database (website). 
1.) How can I move the passed students to next class i.e. which attribute (may be joining year) I have to use to sort them out ?

2.) After 10th Class when students leave the school how can I hide their data from database and move 9th class students record to 10th class.
I am using codeigniter and mysql for my website.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

For your question, The Logic should be in JAVA or PHP or C# or some server side script.

1. For your first question, write a prepared statement (using a prepared statement is a Good practice, reusability, etc.., even you can have simple join query) to check the grades of the student, if they passed Update teh class to current+1, else do nothing
2. For your second question, You can add an attribute Active in Student Table and make a default value Yes, If He/She (Student) left the school, then UPDATE it to No